# Indy-cli crashed when executing did new seed

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I am using indy-node and indy-sdk on CentOS 7 vm. And want to connect vonx.io (http://greenlight.bcovrin.vonx.io/). Connection and wallet creation are ok but create new did failed.

```
indy> pool create sandbox gen_txn_file=./vonx_pool_txn_genesis
Pool config "sandbox" has been created
indy> pool connect sandbox
Pool "sandbox" has been connected
pool(sandbox):indy> wallet create allen_wallet key=123
Wallet "allen_wallet" has been created
pool(sandbox):indy> wallet open allen_wallet key=123
Wallet "allen_wallet" has been opened
pool(sandbox):allen_wallet:indy> did new seed=000000000000000000000000AllenDID
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'attempted to leave type `linked_hash_map::Node<std::string::String, raw_statement::RawStatement>` uninitialized, which is invalid', /rustc/a178d0322ce20e33eac124758e837cbd80a6f633/library/core/src/mem/mod.rs:660:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 0):

The error might be caused by a bug introduced by linked-hash-map library. It’s been fixed in the PR [Update Rusqlite to version 0.25.3 by mirgee · Pull Request #2402 · hyperledger/indy-sdk · GitHub](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/pull/2402)

You just need to build libindy `1.16.0` from the commit [efb72154d](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/commit/efb72154dab94498861c43f9ac5208174e9b702c) containing merge commit of the PR above.